# Use Dask to run PyBaMM battery simulations in parallel

Tags: python, dask

I'm using the [PyBaMM](https://www.pybamm.org) package to model battery cells and I would like to use Dask to run several simulations in parallel. The example below is my attempt to use `dask.delayed`. The Dask approach is slower than the non-Dask approach. Is there a better way to use Dask for this example? Should I setup a Dask `Client()` to run the simulations in parallel? I'm running this example on my local machine but I would eventually like to run a similar example on a cluster.

Elapsed times from running the example on an 8-core MacBook Pro are given below. Comment out the appropriate section in `main()` to run with or without Dask.

| Example | Elapsed time |
| --- | --- |
| No Dask | 8.02 seconds |
| Dask | 8.74 seconds |

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pybamm
import time
import dask

def generate_plots(discharge, t, capacity, current, voltage):

    def styleplot(ax):
        ax.legend(loc='best')
        ax.grid(color='0.9')
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
        ax.tick_params(color='0.9')

    _, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(len(discharge)):
        ax.plot(t[i], current[i], label=f'{discharge[i]} A')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Current [A]')
    styleplot(ax)

    _, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(len(discharge)):
        ax.plot(t[i], voltage[i], label=f'{discharge[i]} A')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Terminal voltage [V]')
    styleplot(ax)

    _, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(len(discharge)):
        ax.plot(capacity[i], voltage[i], label=f'{discharge[i]} A')
    ax.set_xlabel('Discharge capacity [Ah]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Terminal voltage [V]')
    styleplot(ax)

    plt.show()

def run_simulation(dis, t_eval):

    model = pybamm.lithium_ion.SPMe()

    param = model.default_parameter_values
    param['Current function [A]'] = '[input]'

    sim = pybamm.Simulation(model, parameter_values=param)
    sim.solve(t_eval, inputs={'Current function [A]': dis})

    return sim.solution

def main():
    tic = time.perf_counter()

    discharge = [4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.8, 1.5, 1]  # discharge currents [A]
    t_eval = [0, 4000]                            # evaluation time [s]

    # No Dask
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    label = 'no Dask'

    sols = []
    for dis in discharge:
        sol = run_simulation(dis, t_eval)
        sols.append(sol)

    # Dask
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # label = 'Dask'

    # lazy_sols = []
    # for dis in discharge:
    #     sol = dask.delayed(run_simulation)(dis, t_eval)
    #     lazy_sols.append(sol)

    # sols = dask.compute(*lazy_sols)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    t = []
    capacity = []
    current = []
    voltage = []

    for sol in sols:
        t.append(sol['Time [s]'].entries)
        capacity.append(sol['Discharge capacity [A.h]'].entries)
        current.append(sol['Current [A]'].entries)
        voltage.append(sol["Terminal voltage [V]"].entries)

    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Elapsed time ({label}) = {toc - tic:.2f} s')

    generate_plots(discharge, t, capacity, current, voltage)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you provide [a minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your problem? That would help in diagnosing where your code might be slowing down. Also have you tried running Dask with the distributed scheduler by instantiating a Client() object? see here https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/setup/single-distributed.html#single-machine-dask-distributed

Comment: @rrpelgrim I provided a code example in my question. You should be able to run it using the latest version of Python and the associated packages.

Comment: it's a code example but I wouldn't call it minimal. There's a lot of code for me to sift through here to get to your problem. I (and others with me) are more likely to engage if the problem is boiled down to a generally applicable form. Also, first thing I would try is using the distributed scheduler as mentioned above.

Comment: using the distributed scheduler will allow you to inspect the Dask dashboard which should be able to tell you if your simulations are actually running in parallel.

Comment: you can access the address of the dashboard with client.get_dashboard()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from @rrpelgrim, I implemented a `Client()` object which appears to improve the parallel execution of my example code by using the distributed scheduler. The modified example is shown below. You can compare the elapsed time with and without Dask by commenting out the appropriate section in `main()`. Elapsed times using an 8-core CPU are given in the table.

| Example | Elapsed time |
| --- | --- |
| No Dask | 8.57 seconds |
| Dask | 3.83 seconds |

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pybamm
import time
from dask.distributed import Client

def create_plots(discharge, t, capacity, current, voltage):

    def styleplot(ax, xlabel, ylabel):
        ax.legend(loc='best')
        ax.grid(color='0.9')
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
        ax.tick_params(color='0.9')
        ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)

    _, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(len(discharge)):
        ax.plot(t[i], current[i], label=f'{discharge[i]} A')
    styleplot(ax, xlabel='Time [s]', ylabel='Current [A]')

    _, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(len(discharge)):
        ax.plot(t[i], voltage[i], label=f'{discharge[i]} A')
    styleplot(ax, xlabel='Time [s]', ylabel='Terminal voltage [V]')

    _, ax = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(len(discharge)):
        ax.plot(capacity[i], voltage[i], label=f'{discharge[i]} A')
    styleplot(ax, xlabel='Discharge capacity [Ah]', ylabel='Terminal voltage [V]')

    plt.show()

def run_simulation(dis, t_eval):

    model = pybamm.lithium_ion.SPMe()

    param = model.default_parameter_values
    param['Current function [A]'] = '[input]'

    sim = pybamm.Simulation(model, parameter_values=param)
    sim.solve(t_eval, inputs={'Current function [A]': dis})

    return sim.solution

def main(client):
    tic = time.perf_counter()

    discharge = [4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.8, 1.5, 1]  # discharge currents [A]
    t_eval = [0, 4000]                            # evaluation time [s]

    # No Dask
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # label = 'no Dask'

    # sols = []
    # for dis in discharge:
    #     sol = run_simulation(dis, t_eval)
    #     sols.append(sol)

    # Dask
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    label = 'Dask'

    lazy_sols = client.map(run_simulation, discharge, t_eval=t_eval)
    sols = client.gather(lazy_sols)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    t = []
    capacity = []
    current = []
    voltage = []

    for sol in sols:
        t.append(sol['Time [s]'].entries)
        capacity.append(sol['Discharge capacity [A.h]'].entries)
        current.append(sol['Current [A]'].entries)
        voltage.append(sol["Terminal voltage [V]"].entries)

    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Elapsed time ({label}) = {toc - tic:.2f} s')

    create_plots(discharge, t, capacity, current, voltage)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    print(client)
    main(client)
```

Comment: Great to see this was helpful! If I'm not mistaken, you could just keep your delayed tasks as they were, no need to switch to the client.map / gather API. Having instantiated your Client() object, Dask should use that (i.e. the distributed scheduler) automatically to run the parallelise the delayed tasks.

Comment: @rrpelgrim What is the difference and/or advantage of using `dask.delayed` and `dask.computer` vs using `client.map` and `client.gather`?

Comment: From the docs: "[The Futures] interface (i.e. client.map, client.gather etc.) is good for arbitrary task scheduling like dask.delayed, but is immediate rather than lazy, which provides some more flexibility in situations where the computations may evolve over time." https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html?highlight=client.map#futures